# mysql table values merged into one value instead of multiple

Tags: php, css, mysql

i've ran into an issue with my code which has left me stumped. in the code below, i have created a table for mysql data to be fetched into. however when running my code all of the data (which includes titles, descriptions and prices), seem to be merged into one continuous row which fills the entire page. i'm not sure if this has to do with the size of the data i'm trying to fit into a specific row, or a fault in my code. so any help would be appreciated.

styling used:

```
    table {
          border: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 15px;
     }

     th {
         background-color: #a6a6a6;
         color: white;
     }

     table td {
         font-size: 5px;
         border-left: 1px solid #000;
     border-right: 1px solid #000;
     }

     table td:first-child {
     border-left: none;
 }

     table td:last-child {
     border-right: none;
 }

</style>
```

table and php:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Event Title:</th>
                    <th>Event Category:</th>
                    <th>Event Description:</th>
                    <th>Venue:</th>
                    <th>Opening Date:</th>
                    <th>Closing Date:</th>
                    <th>Price:</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
  <?php //Beginig of php script for database events

    include "Database_connection.php"; //Will make the database connection

    $sql = "
SELECT e.eventTitle
     , c.catDesc
     , e.eventDescription
     , v.venueName
     , e.eventStartDate
     , e.eventEndDate
     , e.eventPrice 
  FROM NEE_venue v
  JOIN NEE_events e
    ON e.venueID = v.venueID
  JOIN NEE_category c
    ON c.catID = e.catID
 ORDER 
    BY eventTitle ASC
";
    $queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);

    if($queryResult === false) { //will detect if the connection failed, and give an error message
        echo "<p>Query failed: ".$dbConn->error."</p>\n</body>\n</html>";
        exit;
      }

      else { //if connection is succsessful, code will retrive the events
        while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "<tr><td>". $row["eventTitle"] ."</td><td>". $row["catDesc"] ."</td><td>". $row["eventDescription"] ."</td><td>". $row["venueName"] ."</td><td>". $row["eventStartDate"] ."</td><td>". $row["eventEndDate"] ."</td><td>". $row["eventPrice"]
                        ."</td></tr>";
        }
                    echo "</table>";
      }
      $queryResult->close();
      $dbConn->close();
      ?>
```

screenshot of the issue:

[mysql issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGiz3.png)

Comment: What does the source code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the end table tag in the top section.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Event Title:</th>
                <th>Event Category:</th>
                <th>Event Description:</th>
                <th>Venue:</th>
                <th>Opening Date:</th>
                <th>Closing Date:</th>
                <th>Price:</th>
          </tr>
        </table> <---  That one.
```

Looks like from both the code and the image that the data gets printed outside of the table, because the end table tag gets added too early.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you so much. i've spent way too much time trying to fix that.